# Setting selection criteria for rows in joined tabled

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How do I set criteria for limiting results in joined tables? Consider these two classes (only including fields relevant for this question):

```
// A customers account
public class PaymentAccount {
   private int paymentaccountno;
   private Set<PaymentAccountItem> accountitems;
}

// Some invoice item related to the account above
public class PaymentAccountItem {
   private int paymentaccountitemno;
   private boolean invoiced;
}
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between PaymentAccount and PaymentAccountItem as follows:

```
<class name="PaymentAccount" table="paymentaccount">
 <id name="paymentaccountno">
  <generator class="sequence">
   <param name="sequence_name">paymentaccount_paymentaccountno_seq</param>
  </generator>
 </id>
 <set name="accountitems" table="paymentaccountitem" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
  <key column="paymentaccountno" />
  <one-to-many class="PaymentAccountItem" />
  </set>
</class>

<class name="PaymentAccountItem" table="paymentaccountitem">
 <id name="paymentaccountitemno">
  <generator class="sequence">
   <param name="sequence_name">paymentaccountitem_paymentaccountitemno_seq</param>
  </generator>
 </id>
 <property name="invoiced" />
</class>
```

I want to get a list of all PaymentAccount objects but (for this case) the accountitems-Set should only contain objects having "invoiced=false".

Was I to write the SQL-query myself I would do something like:

```
SELECT * from paymentaccount pa, paymentaccountitem pai WHERE pa.paymentaccountno=pai.paymentaccountno AND pai.invoiced=false;
```

How do I get Hibernate to do this for me (preferably keeping my code nice and SQL-free if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the result of your query wont be an entity, you might try this :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"SELECT * from paymentaccount pa, paymentaccountitem pai WHERE pa.paymentaccountno=pai.paymentaccountno AND pai.invoiced=false");
List result = query.list();
```